# Value of type '_' has no member 'count' and 'indexPath'

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

everyone! I have a problem when I am connecting JSON with the table view. There are two mistakes in the functions:

> Value of type 'BalanceStruct?' has no member 'count'

and

> Value of type 'BalanceStruct?' has no member 'indexPath'

```
import UIKit

class BalanceViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    var balances: BalanceStruct?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ServerManager.shared.getBalanceList(token: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token") as! String, { (balanceList) in
            self.balances = balanceList
            self.tableView.delegate = self
            self.tableView.dataSource = self
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
        {(error) in print(error)}

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return balances.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let balance = balances.indexPath.row
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BalanceCell", for: indexPath) as! BalancesViewCell
        cell.configure(balances: balance)
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

and the problem is in this part:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return balances.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let balance = balances.indexPath.row

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BalanceCell", for: indexPath) as! BalancesViewCell
    cell.configure(balances: balance)
    return cell
}
```

BalanceStruct is a model

```
struct BalanceStruct: Codable {
    let content: [ContentBS]
    let pageable: Pageable
    let totalPages, totalElements: Int
    let last: Bool
    let sort: Sort
    let numberOfElements: Int
    let first: Bool
    let size, number: Int
    let empty: Bool
}

// MARK: - Content
struct ContentBS: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let dateCreated: String
    let dateUpdated: String?
    let name: String
    let balance: Int
}
```

How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: What is `BalanceStruct`? When you do `self.tableView.delegate`, it's because a `tableView` which is a `UITableView` has a property `delegate`, right? So why balance should have a property `count` ? Or a property `indexPath`? I think you want an array, but show what's `BalanceStruct` supposed to be.

Comment: BalanceStruct is a model
`struct BalanceStruct: Codable {
    let content: [ContentBS]
    let pageable: Pageable
    let totalPages, totalElements: Int
    let last: Bool
    let sort: Sort
    let numberOfElements: Int
    let first: Bool
    let size, number: Int
    let empty: Bool
}

// MARK: - Content
struct ContentBS: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let dateCreated: String
    let dateUpdated: String?
    let name: String
    let balance: Int
}`

Comment: What do you want to show in a cell? a `ContentBS`, or a `BalanceStruct`? That's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table view data source must be an **array** (or at least a collection type)

```
var balances = [BalanceStruct]()
```

Then the data source methods are

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return balances.count // works
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let balance = balances[indexPath.row] // must be index subscription

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BalanceCell", for: indexPath) as! BalancesViewCell
    cell.configure(balances: balance)
    return cell
}
```

---

However if the `content` array is supposed to be displayed replace

```
var balances = [BalanceStruct]()
```

with

```
var contentBS = [ContentBS]()
```

and

```
self.balances = balanceList
```

with

```
self.contentBS = balanceList.content
```

Now the data source methods are

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contentBS.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let balance = contentBS[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BalanceCell", for: indexPath) as! BalancesViewCell
    cell.configure(balances: balance)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: But when I am using it as an array there is a problem: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to display in the table view. This error is related to the JSON decoding in `ServerManager`. Print `error` not `error.localizedDescription` to get the **real** error.

Comment: What error? Where? Is that really a BalanceStruct per cell or a ContentBS per cell? All the logic will change if we know what you want to do in fact.